# Native checksum table says there's a difference, pt-table-checksum does not

Tags: mysql, replication, percona-tools

I was setting up a slave and doing some table checksums to check things were ok before getting them live.

I did a native mysql checksum tables on the slaves after syncing slaving to a stopped point and comparing against a preexisting slave.

Two tables differed.  To drill down I ran pt-table-checksum which reported both the old and new slave had no differences and the same row counts.

To get a third opinion I did a select * into outfile ordered by PK and ran an md5sum on the outputs.  Those too both matched.

One noticeable difference is the newer slave is running a slighter newer version (5.5.34 vs 5.5.29); both percona builds.

Is this version difference something to be expected in causing differences in checksums?  If so it seems odd it was just two tables out have a couple dozen.

Comment: by any chance is innodb_locks_unsafe_for_binlog enabled? I've seen false positives with this option

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't worry, your situation is not unique. I encountered the exact same problem with [mk-table-checksum](http://www.maatkit.org/doc/mk-table-sync.html) years ago (See my `Nov 16, 2012` post [Maatkit shows the MySQL replication error in one table, but won't fix it](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/28830/maatkit-shows-the-mysql-replication-error-in-one-table-but-wont-fix-it/28832#28832))

Here is something frightening from the [**MySQL Documentation on CHECKSUM TABLE**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/checksum-table.html)

> The checksum value depends on the table row format. If the row format
>   changes, the checksum also changes. For example, the storage format
>   for VARCHAR changed between MySQL 4.1 and 5.0, so if a 4.1 table is
>   upgraded to MySQL 5.0, the checksum value may change.
>
> Important If the checksums for two tables are different, then it is
>   almost certain that the tables are different in some way. However,
>   because the hashing function used by CHECKSUM TABLE is not guaranteed
>   to be collision-free, there is a slight chance that two tables which
>   are not identical can produce the same checksum.

I meniotned this caveat before back in January 2012 : [How to check the consistency of tables in mysql](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/10822/how-to-check-the-consistency-of-tables-in-mysql/10823#10823)

Sometimes, I just like directly using mk-table-sync (sorry Percona, I'm old fashioned)  with the `--print` options and tell me the SQL differences. As the MySQL Documentation says, there could be differences because of the VARCHAR alignment or ROW FORMAT. If mk-table-sync/pt-table-sync insists there are no changes, you could trust it 99.9 % of the time. If you don't trust it, mysqldump the table and reload it. Chances are the checksum may not match again.